# Google Cloud Build - Terraform Self-Destruction on Build Failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-build, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm currently facing an issue with my Google Cloud Build for CI/CD.

- First, I build new docker images of multiple microservices and use Terraform to create the GCP infrastructure for the containers that they will also live in production.
- Then I perform some Integration / System Tests and if everything is fine I push new versions of the microservice images to the container registry for later deployment.

My problem is, that the Terraformed infrastructure doesn't get destroyed if the cloud build fails.

Is there a way to always execute a cloud build step even if some previous steps have failed, here I would want to always execute "terraform destroy"?
Or specifically for Terraform, is there a way to define a self-destructive Terraform environment?

#### cloudbuild.yaml example with just one docker container

```
steps:

    # build fresh ...
    - id: build 
      name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      dir: '...'
      args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/staging/...:latest', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/staging/...:$BUILD_ID', '.', '--file', 'production.dockerfile']

    # push
    - id: push
      name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
      dir: '...'
      args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/staging/...']
      waitFor: [build]

    # setup terraform
    - id: terraform-init
      name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28'
      dir: '...'
      args: ['init']
      waitFor: [push]

    # deploy GCP resources
    - id: terraform-apply 
      name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28'
      dir: '...'
      args: ['apply', '-auto-approve']
      waitFor: [terraform-init]

    # tests
    - id: tests
      name: 'python:3.7-slim'
      dir: '...'
      waitFor: [terraform-apply]
      entrypoint: /bin/sh
      args:
       - -c
       - 'pip install -r requirements.txt && pytest ... --tfstate terraform.tfstate'

    # remove GCP resources
    - id: terraform-destroy
      name: 'hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28'
      dir: '...'
      args: ['destroy', '-auto-approve']
      waitFor: [tests]
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to share how you've configured your Google Cloud Build pipeline?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I added an example cloud build yaml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Build doesn't yet support `allow_failure` or some similar mechanism as mentioned in [this unsolved but closed issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/253).

What you can do, and as mentioned in the linked issue, is to chain shell conditional operators.

If you want to run a command on failure then you can do something like this:

```yaml
    - id: tests
      name: 'python:3.7-slim'
      dir: '...'
      waitFor: [terraform-apply]
      entrypoint: /bin/sh
      args:
       - -c
       - pip install -r requirements.txt && pytest ... --tfstate terraform.tfstate || echo "This failed!"
```

This would run your test as normal and then echo `This failed!` to the logs if the tests fail. If you want to run `terraform destroy -auto-approve` on the failure then you would need to replace the `echo "This failed!"` with `terraform destroy -auto-approve`. Of course you will also need the Terraform binaries in the Docker image you are using so will need to use a custom image that has both Python and Terraform in it for that to work.

```yaml
    - id: tests
      name: 'example-customer-python-and-terraform-image:3.7-slim-0.12.28'
      dir: '...'
      waitFor: [terraform-apply]
      entrypoint: /bin/sh
      args:
       - -c
       - pip install -r requirements.txt && pytest ... --tfstate terraform.tfstate || terraform destroy -auto-approve ; false"
```

The above job also runs `false` at the end of the command so that it will return a non 0 exit code and mark the job as failed still instead of only failing if `terraform destroy` failed as well.

An alternative to this would be to use something like [Test Kitchen](https://kitchen.ci/) which will automatically stand up infrastructure, run the necessary verifiers and then destroy it at the end all in a single `kitchen test` command.

It's probably also worth mentioning that your pipeline is entirely serial so you don't need to use `waitFor`. This is mentioned in the [Google Cloud Build documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#build_steps):

> A build step specifies an action that you want Cloud Build to perform.
> For each build step, Cloud Build executes a docker container as an
> instance of `docker run`. Build steps are analogous to commands in a
> script and provide you with the flexibility of executing arbitrary
> instructions in your build. If you can package a build tool into a
> container, Cloud Build can execute it as part of your build. By
> default, Cloud Build executes all steps of a build serially on the
> same machine. If you have steps that can run concurrently, use the
> [`waitFor`](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#waitfor) option.

[and](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#waitfor)

> Use the `waitFor` field in a build step to specify which steps must run
> before the build step is run. If no values are provided for `waitFor`,
> the build step waits for all prior build steps in the build request to
> complete successfully before running. For instructions on using
> `waitFor` and `id`, see Configuring build step order.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will have a look at Test Kitchen. I know this is off-topic, but do you know if it is possible to remove the push step to container registry and pass the local docker image to terraform? In the beste case, I only want to push the docker images to the container registry after they have been tested successfully.

Comment: That's a separate question and should be raised as another question so that people can focus on that one thing.

Comment: This follow up question can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62784111/using-local-docker-images-in-terraform

Comment: Could you accept the answer if it solved your issue? It would help the community to better find answers.